# How can I find unrun code in my Eclipse Java program?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Maybe it is a naive question, but I am running the source code of a java application on eclipse and I need to extract one specific functionality from all the application. Is there any way to highlight or identify the chunk of codes which were not ran after an execution?. I am using Eclipse 2018-09.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking for. Anyway, you can put `System.out.println` statement with some random text in your block to make sure whether it is executed or not.

Comment: Run the program with code coverage option? See [Eclemma](http://www.eclemma.org/)

Comment: But note: "unrun" code depends on how exactly your "drive" your application when measuring coverage.

Answer (score 0):

One way to identify which code were executed is to write a test case and run java code coverage maven plugin or run sonar for the test case, if you are using maven project. jacoco-maven-plugin is the plugin name. You can check more details in https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/improve-java-code-with-unit-tests-and-jacoco-b342643736ed.

Answer (score 0):

**You can install SonarLint  plugin**

How to install SonarLint to eclipse , Follow the steps here

1. Click on Help
2. Eclipse Market Place
3. Search , SonarLint plugin
4. SonarLint plugin can be found in Eclipse MarketPlace by searching
5. Restart eclipse
6. you will see under line error that  chunk of codes which were not used to anything